# ParticleEmitter depreciated

Tags: unity-game-engine

In unity I have this block of code:

```
  private IEnumerator ShowEffectCouroutine (Transform fadingStar)
    {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.5f);
    fadingStar.Find ("Effect").GetComponent<ParticleEmitter> ().emit =  true;
    }
```

is no longer working in the new version of unity so it is changed to . My question is what should be the replacement value of .emit?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Legacy_Particle_System_Updater.cs](https://forum.unity.com/attachments/legacy_particle_system_updater-cs.292598/) provided by Unity to update all of your Particle related systems:

https://forum.unity.com/threads/release-legacy-particle-system-updater.510879/

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the legacy particle system is obsolete and will be removed soon. Consider using the new [particle system](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ParticleSystem.html). 
[Here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.Emit.html) you can see how to use the new system to emit particles from script.