# Update ParticleEmitter references using Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I built an application using `Unity 3D` years ago.

Now, I'm trying to rebuild it.

But I get an error in this line:

```
GetComponent<ParticleEmitter>().worldVelocity = new Vector3 (Random.Range(-10,10),0,Random.Range(-10,10));
```

Seems like `ParticleEmitter` [is obsolete through the unity documentation.](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/ParticleEmitter.Emit.html)

Exist a new method/class or something to make a simple update of this line without affect whole my code with a large process?

I read this post:

[ParticleEmitter depreciated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53431961/particleemitter-depreciated)

but, the `ParticleSystem` doesn't have any `Verctor3` method to make a simple update.

Can someone help me to fix it?